# HTML Autocomplete of tags not working in VS Code in Vue

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs2, vetur

I have started learning VueJS and I noticed that in my .vue files, I no longer have HTML autocomplete(auto closing of tags) inside my `<template>` tags. I am using VSCode 1.64.1. I am using Vetur 0.35.0 and my settings.json looks like this:

```
"[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"
 },
 "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
        "vue-html": "html",
        "vue": "html",
  },
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the problem is with your Emmet syntax profile settings. Try updating your settings.json file to the following:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"vue-html": "html",
"vue": "html"
```

},

This will tell Emmet to include HTML syntax when working with .vue files, allowing you to use HTML auto-completion and auto-closing of tags within your  tags.